# Can I add a background image to an animated GGplot using gganimate?

Tags: ggplot2, background-image, gganimate

I am trying to add a background image of an enclosed space map to my gganimate scatterplot project that tracks animal movements. This space is too small for a map so using GPS and raster files are not an option. I have overlayed the enclosure space coordinates on a grid. The animation works fine, but when I add the background image using the following line of code:

`````
````background_image(img)```
`````

I get the following error message:

````
```Error in UseMethod("units<-") : 
   no applicable method for 'units<-' applied to an object of class "NULL"```
````

Here is my code:

````
```{r}
  ggplot(map) + 
  aes(x = X_Coord, y = Y_Coord, color = Individual) +
  background_image(img) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  theme_apa() +
  labs(title = 'Time: {frame_time}', x = 'X Coordinate (m)', y = 'Y Coordinate (m)') +
  transition_time(`Time(24H)`) +
  ease_aes('linear') +
  shadow_mark(alpha = 0.3, size = 1)
```
````

Does gganimate allow adding background images to the plot?

Comment: Please clarify where the `background_image` function comes from.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your comment. background_image comes from the ggpubr package